# Headphone Jack Has Fallen Silent

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-8.1, drivers, speakers

I have an odd problem, and I'm stumped--which doesn't happen often :P

The short version is that the headphone jack on my laptop (Dell Precision M4500, running Win8.1) is not outputting any sound. Sounds (ha) simple, no? Nope. Here's what I've done/determined so far.

First and foremost, **it is not failed hardware**. I dual-boot Ubuntu (for fun, Windows required for work), and everything's working just dandy over there--plug/unplug switching between jack and onboard speakers, separate volume control, everything.

Driver is as updated as it can be--the driver from Dell support is not supported on Win8.1 (this is a Win7-era rig), but it's the newest version from Windows Update. Also, the driver has not been updated before or after failure--near as I can tell, there has only ever been one version.

I have already gone into devmgmt and removed the audio drivers, then rebooted and let Windows reinstall them.

The external jack is set as default, when available. If plugged, it actually kills the internal speakers--so Windows *is* detecting when it is plugged/unplugged.

Interface-specific volume control is not the problem. In fact, in dealing with this, I have the volume mixer set up so that I see the volume control for both at all times. Both are up and not muted.

Have restarted the Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder services--in fact, a few times that I did so, I got some weird behavior immediately afterward, like where I'd plug in the jack and the sound management interface would say that it was playing through the jack, but it was playing through the onboard speakers.

Have run SFC, it came back saying that everything was golden, so I'm not losing system files or anything.

Maybe if I wipe and reregister the audio service? It runs in svchost, not its own executable, so not totally certain how to go about doing so without killing it.

If anyone knows any REALLY fancy tricks I could try, it'd be great. I'm betting reloading Windows would do it, but that's like using a thermonuclear device to mow your lawn.

Comment: Did this happen with the latest round of Windows updates (March 2015) or before?

Comment: Hm. I hadn't noticed that there was a round of updates. Just checked, and since I updated at the end of January, they've dropped over 2GB of updates.